# Is it possible to handle event, closing process apps

Tags: vb.net

How can I determine if my process.start was closed or exited? Is it possible that there is an event when closing the browser? I am trying to create a code like these: If  Process.Exit("iexplore.exe") then, environment.exit(0).

This is my current code, but my problem is how can I determine if the browser is closed?

```
  Private Sub login(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
       Process.Start("iexplore.exe")
   End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the process to a variable and wait for it to exit:

```
 Private Sub login(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
   Dim ieproc As Process
   ieproc = Process.Start("iexplore.exe")
   ieproc.WaitForInputIdle()
   ieproc.WaitForExit() '<= processing will wait here until the browser is closed
   MsgBox("IE has closed!")
 End sub
```

Or if you don't want to halt processing, don't use the `WaitForExit` and instead use a background process or timer to periodically check if the process has ended...here's a simple example using a timer:

```
 Dim ieproc As Process

 Private Sub login(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
   ieproc = Process.Start("iexplore.exe")
   ieproc.WaitForInputIdle()
   Timer1.Enabled = True
 End sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ieproc.HasExited Then
        Me.Timer1.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("IE has closed!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The logic is good, but im not yet closing my internet browser and its already showing me the message "IE has closed". All I want is when I closed the browser the prompt message will show.

Comment: Using which method the WaitForExit or the Timer? I just tested both and they work. No message box until the browser closes.

Comment: Try adding `ieproc.WaitForInputIdle()`...see my updated code above.

Comment: Now its working I have to close my current browser to enable it. Thanks well done.

Answer (score 0):

Wire up the [Process.Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Event.  You must also enable the [Process.EnableRaisingEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents(v=vs.110).aspx) Property:

```
Private Sub login(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    Dim P As New Process
    P.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe"
    P.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    AddHandler P.Exited, AddressOf P_Exited
    P.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub P_Exited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' ... do something in here ...
End Sub
```